# Generating mirror numbers by reversing and adding digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, palindrome

(This was a question asked by my dear little 10 year old brother.) Let's define some kind of algorithm, where we take a number, reverse its digits, and add it to the original, and iterate until we obtain a palindrome/mirror number. For example:
start with $213$; $213+312=525$, which is a palindrome. We can define this as a "function" $f(213)=535=f(312)$, $f(12)=f(21)=33$, etc.

My brother asked the following two questions:

> - If we begin with $196$, and follow this algorithm, can we ever obtain such a palindromic number? If yes, what's that number? I.e., does $f(196)$ (which is equal to $f(691)$) exist?
> - How about if we begin with $9988$? Is it possible to obtain such a palindromic number? I.e., does $f(9988)$ exist? If yes, what is $f(9988)$?

I couldn't answer him, and so I've resorted to the great minds of MSE.

**P.S.**: I was curious to see whether, if we start with a general number $n=\sum^n_{i=1}a_i10^i$, what will the resulting palindromic number be, if it exists? But this is just a "bonus"! :-)

Comment: Two words: Lychrel numbers. And $4994$ is already a palindrome.

Comment: I think that the algorithm terminates if and only if you **do not** have a pair of "mirroring" digits whose sum is larger than $9$ (where the middle digit, if exists, has to be summed with itself, i.e., cannot be larger than $4$).

Comment: @barakmanos Is there some theoretical calculation that one can do to show that?

Comment: It's just a hunch. I haven't "dug" into this, but it might give you (or someone else reading this post) an idea.

Comment: Well, the 196 one is an unsolved problem, so I doubt it would be that simple.

Comment: I recommend reading through some posts about it at overflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117104/status-of-the-196-conjecture/117277

Comment: Well I gotta admit that if it's an unsolved problem then there's a good chance that "barak's hypothesis" is wrong (thought it was a 10-year old child's question).

Comment: @Sanath There's a whole bunch of them (see http://oeis.org/A023108). If you're interested in them, you might as well add more terms to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have already informed you, this is an open problem several amateur and professional mathematicians have been working on for decades now. According to [a p196.org page](http://p196.org/milestones.html), calculations had advanced past 400 million decimal digits as of 2011.

To give you some perspective, consider that scientists say there are $10^{80}$ atoms in the entire universe. If an odd perfect number exists, it is at least $10^{300}$. It might be the case that the smallest odd perfect number is less than the first palindrome reached from 196 by the reverse-and-add function. You have a better chance of winning a million dollar lottery jackpot than you do of finding a palindrome in 196's trajectory.

As for 4994, most people consider it trivial because it's already a palindrome. The question you need to be asking then is whether 9988 reaches a palindrome by this algorithm. According to [a German Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel-Zahl), if I've understood the language correctly and if the information is correct (two big ifs), 9988's trajectory might never reach a palindrome. But I doubt calculations have gone as far for it as for 196.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I guess my brother will be happy to see this!